# Getting a compressed Neo4j response

Tags: neo4j, compression, gzip, cypher

I'm using Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint from my application to execute queries in Neo4j. I was wondering if there is a way to get zipped response from server.

I read some threads about it but they mentioned to create unmanaged extensions for it:
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/07/08/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-creating-gzipped-streamed-responses-with-jetty/

I just want the zipped response using HTTP endpoints that I'm already using.
I guess setting http parameter in request to tell the server to compress response will not work.

Is there any configuration that can enable the response to get compressed?
Any ideas for unzipping response as well?

Regards,

Rahul

Comment: I'm pretty sure that neo4j doesn't support gzipped reponses or anything like that, so an unmanaged extension is probably your best bet.  I've also heard the suggestion that at some point they'd like to support binary data transfer, which would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Neo4j behind a proxy caring about compression. One example would be using Apache httpd with mod_deflate for compression and mod_proxy_http for the communication with Neo4j.

I've played around some time ago with a mod_proxy setup, see https://github.com/sarmbruster/vagrant_neo4j_modproxy/blob/master/etc/apache2/sites-available/default as a starting point. Be aware this example does not use mod_deflate yet.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Needham implemented it once, it was not a lot of effort, so you can just take his code build it and put it into your server:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/07/08/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-creating-gzipped-streamed-responses-with-jetty/

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to create an unmanaged extension at this point of time. Since i'll be transitioning from single to HA mode for Neo4j soon, I guess I can explore the compression provided by Load Balancers...